# How to pass the bind variable to the copy into statement in snowflake from python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

.execute("copy into tmp_cdp_score_feature from @cdp_json_acpt/data/1 file_format = (type=json)"

as the last value will be varying from 1 to 100 like data/2, data/3, so I  need to pass as variable .

something like

.execute("copy into tmp_cdp_score_feature from @cdp_json_acpt/data/(%s) file_format = (type=json),(2)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy into tmp_stg from @stg_json_acpt/"'%s'" file_format = (type=json), Force=True" %(des1)

des1= path of the s3 object file
It works fine, tested

Comment: out of curiosity, how does it look with the .execute(",,,") added?

Comment: execute.("copy into tmp_stg from @stg_json_acpt/"'%s'" file_format = (type=json), Force=True" %(des1))

Answer (score 1):

I think you might just have your double-quote in the wrong place in your "something like".  And the format for bind variables is a parameter option, as well

```
format: .execute("... WHERE my_column = %s", (value,)) 
pyformat: .execute("... WHERE my_column = %(name)s", {"name": value}) 
qmark: .execute("... WHERE my_column = ?", (value,)) 
numeric: .execute("... WHERE my_column = :1", (value,))
```

Reference documentation:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html

Comment: yeah, for where and insert we can use the separate double quotes but how to use in the copy into statement .

Comment: Are you getting an error?  I thought it'd work the same.

Comment: execute("copy into tmp_feature from @json_acpt/%s file_format = (type=json)",(path))    the value is finally passed to the % s but I am getting the error    "SQL compilation error:\nsyntax error line 1 at position 62 unexpected ''output_24_10.json''.",

Comment: I would check in query history in Snowflake to see what the query actually was.  It sounds like your syntax on the bind is fine, but your COPY INTO statement is incorrect.

Comment: I have found out the way